# Looking for a data list/file/website of the USA Lucky Lottery Retail Locations and historical lucky retailers?

Tags: data-request, database, games

I am looking for a website, data file, list, or something similar of the "lucky" lottery retail locations. Specifically for the Powerball and MegaMillions lottery tickets.

Hopefully listing the store, location, date of win, and amount of win.

Lottery Retailers qualified as “lucky” by meeting one or more of the criteria below:

- Sold at least one $100,000 or higher winning ticket
- Paid out an average of 400 winning tickets per week
- Paid out an average of $4,000 in winning tickets per week

Any help would be greatly appreciated! All I can seem to find is individual local listings and not a complete list.